# Retrieving array from array of arrays?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, reference

```
use strict;
my @a;
my @b = ();
@a = (3, 4);

push @b, [@a];

my @c = @b[0];
print @c;
```

How do I properly retrieve @c? It tells me Scalar value @b[0] better written as $b[0].

(This isn't my real code for privacy reasons, but in the real code I have something like this:

```
my @a = @{$b[$i]};
print @a;
```

This says "Use of uninitialized value," but still prints what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array reference stored in `$b[0]` - which is your situation - then you retrieve it as

```
$ref = $b[0]    # I just want it as a reference
```

or

```
@arr = @{$b[0]} # I want it as a (new) array
```

or

```
$elt = $b[0][1] # I want to directly access the second element
$elt = $b[0]->[1] # alternative syntax, same thing.
```

Answer (score 2):

For details on the syntax for array access see perldata

`@c[0]` is a single element array slice(!)
`$c[0]` is correct

`$c[0]->[0]` is "3" and `$c[0]->[1]` is "4"

For more details on arrays of arrays see perldsc and perllol